# XSLT: How to imitate a flag or break statement in xslt:foreach whiling iterating a List of variable

Tags: xslt

I'm new to xslt, pardon me for any mistakes.
In the xsl program I've got a list of values with variable named as "foo:vars", which contains a list of color values.
There is  a variable declared  as **matchWith**, which can contain any values (not necessarily present in foor:var list)

The Program Should output as:

1. if the variable **matchWith** contains a value which is present in the list **"foo:vars"** then the value should appear in the tag
   `<color_found>` with the matching value.
2. else, the value present in the variable matchWith should appear in another tag named as `<color_not_found>`

Below is the program, that able to give the correct output for case 1, but I fail condition any flag for case 2.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns:foo="http://foo.com" exclude-result-prefixes="foo">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <foo:vars>
    <foo:var name="a1">Yellow</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="b1">red</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="c1">green</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="d1">blue</foo:var>
  </foo:vars>
  <xsl:variable name="matchWith">Yellow</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/foo:vars/foo:var">
      <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$temp=$matchWith">
          <color_found>
            <xsl:value-of select="$matchWith"/>
          </color_found>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `for-each` when you should just check directly whether there is a matching value.

Like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:foo="http://foo.com" exclude-result-prefixes="foo">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <foo:vars>
    <foo:var name="a1">Yellow</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="b1">red</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="c1">green</foo:var>
    <foo:var name="d1">blue</foo:var>
  </foo:vars>
  <xsl:variable name="matchWith">Yellow</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="options"
                  select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/foo:vars/foo:var" />
    <xsl:variable name="isMatch" select="$matchWith = $options" />

    <xsl:element name="color_{ substring('not_', 1, 4 * not($isMatch)) }found">
      <xsl:value-of select="$matchWith" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works for the scenario. Is there a way where I can have  two blocks (can be if, else sort of ) where I need to have different set of statements to be executed if a matching found/ not found.                                     if(matchWith presents) { some code to execute }                                                 else {some other code to be executed }

Comment: @Harish Yes, you can use `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$isMatch">some code to execute</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>some other code to be executed</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>`

Comment: Thanks, it was a great help.

Comment: @Harish: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.